# Get the start position and end position of found named entities in xml

Tags: python, nlp, xml-parsing, named-entity-extraction

I'm new in xml parsing. I have a xml file which has a content and an identified entities (person and location ). Number of "person" entity in the file is close to 10 and "location" is just 3.

```
<em>
Mad Max:
<location>Fury Road</location 
</em>
```

and so on ..

I wanted to extract the content and start position and end position of each of the entities present in the xml file (using Python - for loop). But not sure how to start writing code to get the positions of it from the xml file.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular for-loops (which could lead to problems in the future), you could use the builtin [xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) module in Python.

In your example:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()
```

From here you can get positions, or simply use this module instead of whatever you were planning to do with the xml data.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your quick response. I tried running this code and got only one tag 
<Element 'tagname' at 0*00000#####D#####>.This tag is the root of the xml tags. Location and person tags is inside the body.content

Comment: Yes, you have to go inside of the root variable to find your tag. See the documentation in the link of the answer.